# Open website from within eclipse's internal browser?

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-indigo, gentoo, embedded-browser

Could anyone help me with opening web pages from within Eclipse's internal (embedded) browser? I'm running Linux (tiling window manager) and Eclipse-3.7.2 side-by-side with browser and it's a pain.

I want this to be able to comfortably read requirements from my code and at the same time code. This could be a question for superuser but it's Eclipse related so I guess I have better shot for an answer here.

Thanks in advance.

[image: eclipse]

edit: I'm running gentoo linux and swt-3.7.1 with compiled in xulrunner support.

edit2: adding picture of gui menu in response to answer bellow.
[image: No menu]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know the question is old but I just had the same problem and was able to find the soloution.

The internal browser of SWT is using the webkitgtk browser engine. Because you're running gentoo I suppose you currently have net-libs/webkit-gtk:3 installed which is incompatible with SWT. But this is no problem because you can install the compatible net-libs/webkit-gtk:2 in a new slot.
Just install it like this:
`emerge net-libs/webkit-gtk:2`

After the package is installed the internal webbrowser is working again (for me)

Regards
Martin

Answer (score 5):

Open Window / Customize Perspective... menu then on "Command Group Availability" tab find "Web Browser" entry and make sure it is checked. Then confirm that "Web Browser" is also checked on "Tool Bar Visibility" tab. Then you should see a web browser globe icon on toolbar that would open a web browser editor in the IDE.

Though you'll have to change settings on your picture to use "Internal Web Browser" then it will be opened as an Eclipse editor.

[image]

Comment: No such menu in my eclipse :(. Thanks for effort though.

Comment: How about right click on empty space on Eclipse toolbar? Do you see "Customize Perspective..." menu up there?

Comment: added linux/gtk look at the menu from my perspective, it's clearly not there (look at edited Q).
Probably I'm missing some plugin that is integrated to your version of eclipse or this is windows only feature, not sure.

Comment: I am using it in both SpringSource STS IDE and also in Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. You could try to add Eclipse WTP to your Eclipse installation.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 13.04 using Eclipse it automagically worked, I was not sure which webkit I was missing, so I installed all that seemed relevant, if someone has pinpointed which it is, please comment,

Regards,

Gabriel Medina

```
aptitude install libqt4-webkit libqt5webkit5 libqtscript4-webkit libqtwebkit4 libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Providing an answer for an Ubuntu system to someone asking about a gentoo system might only be helpful if no one else has any idea. However, there's already an accepted answer with a more detailed understanding of what was missing, so why do you think your answer is helpful?