# Issue Editor and Browser for SonarQube in Eclipse are Blank

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I recently installed SonarQube 5.1 on machine on my local network. I have successfully run the Maven plugin on one of my projects and everything seems to be working fine. I also installed the Eclipse plugin (Luna) from the marketplace and have been able to run an analysis within eclipse. The issues show up in the `SonarQube Issues` view. However, both the `SonarQube Issue Editor` and `SonarQube Web Browser` are completely blank.

This appears to be similar to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520551/sonarqube-editor-tab-in-eclipse-shows-nothing), but the bug referenced there has been marked fixed. I would post a screenshot, but I don't have the required reputation.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: What is your operating system? Note that those two views are "web views". It means this is an embedded browser trying to display a specific SQ server URL. Please have a look at SQ server access.log to see what is the URL and try to open it in a regular browser. Eclipse embedded browser is highly dependent on the platform.

Comment: I am running linux. I have no problem accessing the SQ server from a standard web browser (Firefox). There are no entries when I open the SQ embedded browser or if I try click on Edit Issue from the context SQ Issues context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Julien, the tip on the embedded browser led me to the solution. The problem was in fact caused by missing libraries on my system that were preventing the internal browser from functioning properly. The solution was to install the proper webkit-gtk libraries for my system. On Gentoo, the default is to install webkit-gtk:3, which is incompatible with SWT. The correct version can be installed by running `emerge net-libs/webkit-gtk:2` on the command line as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894530/open-website-from-within-eclipses-internal-browser).